# Call API without localhost in the URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing a simple weather app using the openweather API. The problem I faced is that when I call the API the URL calling is `localhost:4200/api...` URL and I have to call the **API URL** only without localhost.

WeatherService.ts

```
private _url: string;

constructor(private http: Http) {

}

set url(url: string) {
    this._url = url;
}

getDataForSingleCity(city: string): Promise<any> {

    this._url = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + city + '&appid=' + key;

    return this.http.get(this._url)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(resp => resp.json().data as any)
                    .catch(this.handleErrors);
}
```

The `city` string is getting passed through an input field.

Comment: You need to provide a protocol for an absolute URI, add `http[s]://`

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I faced is that when I call the API the URL calling is localhost:4200/api...

Cause the url you have in the following:

```
this._url = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + city + '&appid=' + key;
```

is *relative*

## Fix

use absolute urls:

```
this._url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + city + '&appid=' + key;
```